# Create a torch tensor with desired values

Tags: pytorch, tensor, torch

I want to create a torch tensor of size 100 with values 10 and 100.
For example: The following gives a tensor of values between 5 and 6.

```
torch.randint(5,7,(100,))

tensor([6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5,
        6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5,
        5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6,
        5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6,
        6, 6, 5, 6])
```

Instead of this, I want a tensor with values 10 and 100 and I do not want the values between the integers 10 and 100. Tensor should just contain 10 and 100. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the python function random.choice() to create a list of random numbers then convert it to a tensor:

```
import random 
import torch
list_numbers = random.choices([100,10], k=100) 

random_numbers = torch.Tensor(list_numbers)

print(random_numbers)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you sample from `{0, 1}` then a simple mapping from `[0, 1]` to `[10, 100]` will suffice

Here `x -> (b-a)x + a = (100-10)x + 10 = 90x + 10` will work:

```
>>> rand = torch.randint(0, 2, (100,))
tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 0, 0])

>>> 90*rand+10
tensor([ 10,  10, 100, 100, 100, 100,  10, 100, 100, 100, 100,  10,  10, 100,
        100,  10, 100, 100,  10, 100, 100, 100,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10, 100,
         10,  10, 100,  10, 100, 100,  10,  10, 100,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,
        100,  10,  10, 100,  10,  10,  10, 100, 100, 100, 100,  10, 100, 100,
         10,  10, 100,  10, 100,  10, 100,  10, 100, 100,  10,  10,  10,  10,
        100, 100,  10,  10, 100, 100,  10,  10,  10, 100,  10,  10, 100,  10,
        100, 100,  10,  10, 100,  10, 100,  10,  10,  10, 100, 100, 100, 100,
         10,  10])
```